# Use $this-> when calling a class-scoped function (method)?

Tags: php, function, this

Is there a way to codify the following in PHP:

```
class myClass extends parentClass{
    function myFunction(){
        calculate();
    }
}

class parentClass{
    public function calculate(){

    }
}
```

Or is `$this->` always required?

```
class myClass extends parentClass{
    function myFunction(){
        $this->calculate();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cicada can't be harder than asking this question.

Comment: @Cicada Not more difficult than reading the php.net website, a few books, filtering to get the good ones, a few hours of trial and error, unthinking the strict scoping that applies to php variables, and realising that scope is completely different with php functions. But, before I get carried away, I think you're supposed to start your own thread to ask new questions. Thanks for asking tho. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need `$this->` in functions, defined as class methods.

Also you can use global functions out of classes, they neednot `$this->`

Answer (score 1):

```
function myMethod() { echo "Outside Class Scope"; }

class A {
   function myMethod() { echo "Inside Class Scope"; }

   function what_to_call() {
       myMethod();
   }
}
```

What function should PHP execute when it encounters `myMethod()` within class A''s `what_to_call()` method?

Also consider a long chain of inheritance, with each ancestor having its own `myMethod()`. What method should PHP call? The current objects'? The parents'? The grandparents'?

Comment: I like the point about the ambiguity with global methods, but inheritance should not be a problem if PHP did not require `$this->` (it is not in many other languages -- due to polymorphism, it is always the most specific method, unless prefixed with `super`).

Comment: @renesis: true. just illustrating the ambiguity of things.

Comment: Objects can only have one parent and grandparent

Comment: `$this->` don't save us from  long chain of inheritance

Comment: @mike: in php, yeah. but there are languages that allow multiple inheritance, like C++ and Perl.

Comment: @Marc but you are asking about PHP in your question. I'm just saying, if you say "parents'" with the apostrophe after the 's' it means that a PHP object can have more than one parent.

Comment: While you are right in your assessment that that is a stumbling block, you're a few decades late in bringing it up as a problem. A suitable solution has already been found...and implemented...and used...and immitated...and implemented...and used... ...etc, etc, etc....

Comment: @Marc B - I'm no lingustics prof, but I'd say, as the call is inside the class, the context dictates that php should call the member function, not the global one.  Also, given that I always have to use $GLOBALS['varname'] to access global vars, I would expect methods to follow suit... $GLOBALS->function()     just my 2c. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this $this-> when you're calling method

Answer (score 0):

`$this->` must be used if you're referring to a method (i.e. a function defined inside of a class). `calculate()` on it's own refers to a function outside of the class (just like any build-in function), which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this-> my_function
```

This statement is for call an function into a Class :)